# How can two AWS VPCs using the same Customer Gateway for a VPN connection

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

If there are two vendors with seperate VPCs connecting to a single customer gateway for a VPN connection, what are possible configuration options to allow this?

As it stands it seems that AWS only allows a customer gateway to be associated to one vpn connection per region. It's not possible for us to add an additional customer gateway nor change regions.

It doesn't appear possible to route traffic via one VPCs to another.. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/invalid-peering-configurations.html#edge-to-edge-vgw

Answer (score 3):

In VPC, the external IP addresses of one of "your" virtual private gateways and one of "my" virtual private gateways could be the same -- the virtual private gateway (vgw) is the AWS side of the VPN connection, and has two public IP addresses.  As long as your customer gateway and mine have different addresses, that's a unique source/destination address pair, so it works fine with IPSec, for my traffic and yours to hit the same AWS device on the same external IP.

But later, if we were trying to connect my customer gateway to your VPC, and your VPC's virtual gateway had the same external IP address as my VPC's external IP address, that wouldn't work, because the source address and destination address for two VPN connections would be the same.

Apparently, VPC can't handle this exception automatically, because at the time we give it the customer gateway address, the virtual private gateway address has already been assigned.

So the workaround -- brace yourself -- is apparently to "busy out" your vgw by declaring a dummy customer gateway and setting up a connection.

Then, go create a new vgw, which should have different external addresses... and a new customer gateway for your real IP address.

Repeat until you get a pair that is valid, then delete all the unneeded vpn connections and customer and virtual gateway objects.

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5458758371599914#_Toc331767311

This seems a bit convoluted, but I suspect it's a fairly rare occurrence, since the simpler fix is to use a different external IP on the customer gateway where practical... the limit isn't really one per customer gateway, it's one per customer gateway external IP.

Comment: Wow, how did you find that?! It wasn't mentioned in any of the aws forum responses I saw on the this problem. I will try it out and see if it works! Thank you